# How to use img tag in react

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to show my local image into html using react.

[image: Here is my project structure]

I have app.js which is calling Header component.

[image: App.js]

I am trying to add woods.jpg

[image: Header.js]

The image does not exist, why?

[image: html page and error]

I tried different location but couldn't implement it,

```
src={"../w3images/woods.jpg"}
src={"./w3images/woods.jpg"}
src={"/w3images/woods.jpg"}
src="/w3images/woods.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your app is served from `public` (there's a folder I see).

Then you must specify a path relative to that folder.

Something like `../src/w3images/woods.jpg` if your index.html is in `/public/index.html`.

Answer (score 3):

Your images must be on the public repository to be accessed.

Then, you can have an img like that :

```
<img src="/w3images/woods.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Just had the same problem and your answer solved it. Thanks, buddy!